# Share visual assets along with some controllers between two rails apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have two rails apps that I am thinking about merging into one because they share a similar layout. Right now there is a script in one app that pulls the resources from the other app (including a base controller) into the second app. There are a few ways I have been thinking about doing this:

1. Merge the apps with namespaces and upon deploy have a script that creates two separate RPM packages (this is for deployment on CentOS/RHEL) with the appropriate files in it
2. Run one app as the engine of another. Put all the shared controllers and visual assets into the top-level app. Upon deployment rip rip out the engine if I don't need it. (i.e. if it is just the first app and I don't want to give the code of the second app)
3. Create a GEM with the common controllers and CSS/JS and find a way to inject it into each running app.

Any thoughts/ideas? I am thinking of going with number 1 as it will probably be the easiest for development (2 would be easier for deployment I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 4: make three engines (or gems, or engines encapsulated in gems): one for the common stuff, and one for each application's unique stuff?

Comment: I like this approach, and am working on it but have run into nasty HAML/SASS bugs when they are declasred inside engines.

Answer (score 3):

At [Brighter Planet](http://brighterplanet.com) we do (3). Our [shared layout gem](https://github.com/brighterplanet/brighter_planet_layout) supports both Rails 2 and Rails 3.

In particular you'll want to look at:

- [lib/brighter_planet_layout/rails.rb](https://github.com/brighterplanet/brighter_planet_layout/blob/master/lib/brighter_planet_layout/rails.rb) which helps Rails 2
- [lib/brighter_planet_layout/railtie.rb](https://github.com/brighterplanet/brighter_planet_layout/blob/master/lib/brighter_planet_layout/railtie.rb) which helps Rails 3
- [lib/brighter_planet_layout/rake_tasks.rb](https://github.com/brighterplanet/brighter_planet_layout/blob/master/lib/brighter_planet_layout/rake_tasks.rb) which helps you copy shared files into Rails 2 public dirs

Comment: Nice. We use almost the same technique ourselves as well.

Comment: Yep, we also use shared layout gems (and gems for shared models between apps if they share a common DB or API as a source)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating an engine with the common controllers, css, and js, then packaging the engine as a gem.  When you are working locally, you can have both apps point to a shared development copy of the gem using bundler.  To deploy, package the gem with each app, and deploy the whole thing.  There are a lot of benefits to doing it as a gem, like the ability to have different versions of the gem in the future so you don't have to update both apps at the same time.

This seems like a pretty decent engines guide: http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/03/05/rails-3-plugins---part-2---writing-an-engine/.

I'd be very leery of it, and would probably go with the above approach, but you may consider using symlinks to permanently pull files into one or the other of the projects.  I think it's a bad idea, but in some narrow cases it might make sense.  It really depends on your exact situation since it's kind of a nasty hack, but nasty hacks can sometimes solve specific problems eloquently.

Comment: Why are symlinks a bad idea? And how about using both projects as engines and then putting the shared content in a master rails app?

Comment: Symlinks: It really depends on your situation.  The issue with them is that you lose versioning, so when you update one app it updates both.  This means if you make breaking changes in one, you're making them in both.  This is true with a shared engine gem, but you can very easily add versions to the gems and bundle them so you can update the apps separately.

Comment: Engines: I suppose you could use that approach, but I would rather minimize the number of engines, since there are some implementation issues with them.  Nothing major, but I'd rather have shared code in engines and unique code in app since that's what engines are designed for.  If you create a local gem, you have all the benefits of symlinks since you can set the path somewhere on the filesystem, with the ease of adding versions later so if you want to update one project without the other, you can.

Comment: Engines are not only designed for shared code, particularly in Rails 3. It may make sense to have the unique code in an an engine as well (this is the way Spree works).

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, I'd recommend *not* merging the apps. The scenarios of modifying the package on deployment to separate the two apps is error prone, and counter to current quality control procedures-- you want the code you develop to match the deployed app as much as possible.

Given that, you want to look at the different modularity approaches. There are actually lots of options for sharing code:

- gem
- plugin
- library code included with a git submodule or equivalent
- rails engine
- separate deployed app

Probably a shared engine packaged as a gem is the nicest way to go, but it requires you be on the right version of Rails to get the full benefit. Even without an engine, you can get this to work... it'll just take a little more setup.

By "separate deployed app", I mean a third application that has the shared functionality. This may be the needed resources (CSS, JS), and can even be portions of the pages (loaded dynamically). This is potentially a funky solution, but I've seen it work in the right situation.

And any of these solutions requires a bit more effort on the developers' part... but in the end it's better the deployment troubles you'd get by mergine the code bases

Comment: We don't know enough about the use case to say with certainty that the apps shouldn't be merged.

Comment: You're right. There will be use cases where it makes sense to merge the apps. I took the question pretty literally, and if it's really just a shared layout, I'd keep them separate. It's always a battle to keep a rails app from getting too big.

Comment: Yes, if it's just a shared layout, you're right. But a Rails app should be as big as it needs to be.

Comment: The apps share more than just layout. They share some partials and even some lib/ code. That is why I want to package them as engines and have the master app have all the shared code.